# Kinetic.Image config cornerRadius doesn't work

Tags: image, kineticjs

I currently used KineticJS (version:4.2.0) to do something, but when I want to set corner radius for a kinetic image object, it seems it doesn't work at all. Do anyone have any ideas?
My code is like this:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 901,
    height: 532,
});
var bg = new Kinetic.Layer(); // slot's shell
var bgObj = new Image();
bgObj.onload = function() {
    var item = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 901,
        height: 532,
        image: bgObj,
        cornerRadius: 25
    });
    bg.add(item);
    stage.add(bg);
};
bgObj.src = "background.png";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

corner radius currently isn't implemented for Image.  In fact there's an error with the documentation because only Rectangle supports rounded corners.  Images will support rounded corners soon.

Comment: Why didn't the document give it a red mark saying it's not done yet... Thank you so much.